# Hide column field using sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to hide column field using sql query.

My query is:

```
Select Name,Email,Mobile from Table_Reg where Email not in('raj@gmail.com')
```

So i am not getting raj@gmail.com user details and output like below.

```
Name          Email         Mobile
Mazhar   mazhar@gmail.com   9030349582
```

I need to visible false email Id while in select query and also I want to add `where email not in` condition compulsory and I dont want to show email detail but email condition should compulsory. Output should like below.

```
 Name      Mobile
 Mazhar    9030349582
```

Comment: uhm....what?. So you want `SELECT Name, Mobile FROM Table_Reg WHERE Email <> 'raj@gmail.com'`?

Comment: whatever fields you want then include them in select

Comment: but if i will remove email means how to match where condition. @RameshYelda

Comment: @mazhar124 ...what?, did you try the code in my previous comment?

Comment: that doesn't matter that whether you have included that in select or not. Based on condition you have given in where clause result will come

Comment: <> means what? and please update your answer.@Lamak

Comment: You do not need to have the columns in your where clause also in your list of selected columns. Have you tried what @Lamak suggested?

Comment: `<>` means `not equal`. You can use `NOT IN` if you want, but that's typically to fileter more than one element

Comment: <> means not equal. Check out https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp.

Comment: but I am not achieving my answer. @Lamak

Comment: Select Name,Email(visible=false),Mobile from Table_Reg where Email not in('raj@gmail.com') in select email should be there but visible false. @Lamak

Comment: sorry, what?, what does the Email(visible=false) means??. That's not what you posted in your question

Comment: I am doing export to excel using select query but i dont want that email into export to excel, please tell me visible false but email should be in select query. @SLWS

Comment: Can you tell me how to visible false to the column while selecting. @SLWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you actually need but give a go for below query:

```
Select 
    Name,
    case when Email in ('raj@gmail.com') then 'not visible'
        else Email
    end as Email,
    Mobile 
from Table_Reg
```

Comment: so I guess this is what you needed?

Comment: Kudos to @PawelCz for figuring out that's what was being sought.